# Solve a (not difficult) differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is $\frac{dy}{dx}=A\cdot y+B\cdot e^{Cx}+D$.

I have information of $A>0,B>0, C<0$

This is a problem I encountered in other fields. After I tried for some time I gave up. I'm not studying differential equations and I think this problem should not be hard for those who study.

Thanks to whoever helps.

Comment: Maybe writing a solution with the $A,B,C$ and $D$ could be very messy. I'm looking for the form of $y$, or to say, how $y$ changes(shifts,scale, etc) when the constant $D$ increases.

Comment: Here is the [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%28x%29+%3D+A*y%28x%29%2BB*e%5E%28C*x%29%2BD).

Comment: Whoever made CAS is underappreciated...

Comment: this is covered in "integrating factor method" in most texts. Bring $A y$ to left and multiply the entire equation with $e^{-Ax}$. Write the left side as a complete derivative, $(y e^{-Ax})' $.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

A differential equation on the form
$$y'(x) + p(x)y(x) = q(x) $$
has the solution given by
$$y(x) = e^{-P(x)}\int e^{P(x)}q(x)\,\mathrm{d}x,$$
where $P(x)$ is any antiderivative of $p(x)$, e.g. with integration constant $0$. In English this is called the integrating factor method.

Comment: A remark: it is called the integrating factor method because the steps can be viewed as "multiply both sides by $e^{P(x)}$, notice that the left side is now $\frac{d}{dx} \left ( e^{P(x)} y(x) \right )$; integrate both sides and solve for $y$." So $e^{P(x)}$ is a *factor* that has been introduced to make the equation solvable by *integration*.